# hello friends i cant execute my else condition

Tags: python-3.x

The program must accept a string S as the input. The program must replace every vowel in the string S by the next consonant (alphabetical order) and replace every consonant in the string S by the next vowel (alphabetical order). Finally, the program must print the modified string as the output.

```
s=input()

z=[let for let in s]

alpa="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

a=[let for let in alpa]

v="aeiou"

vow=[let for let in v]


for let in z:

    if(let=="a"or let=="e" or let=="i" or let=="o" or let=="u"):

        index=a.index(let)+1

        if index!="a"or index!="e"or index!="i"or index!="o"or index!="u":

               print(a[index],end="")
    else:

        for let in alpa:

            ind=alpa.index(let)

            i=ind+1

            if(i=="a"or i=="e" or i=="i"or i=="o"or i=="u"):

                print(i,end="")
```

the output is :

```
i/p orange

pbf
```

the required output is:

```
i/p orange 

puboif
```

Comment: What do you do with those constonants that come after all of the vowels?  `"vwxyz"`

Answer (score 0):

Here I use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to split the alphabet into runs of vowels and consonants.  I then create a mapping of letters to the next letter of the other type (ignoring the final consonants in the alphabet).  I then use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#str.maketrans) to build a translation table I can pass to [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#str.translate) to convert the string.

```
from itertools import groupby
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters

vowels = "aeiou"

is_vowel = vowels.__contains__

partitions = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(letters, is_vowel)]

mapping = {}
for curr_letters, next_letters in zip(partitions, partitions[1:]):
    for letter in curr_letters:
        mapping[letter] = next_letters[0]

table = str.maketrans(mapping)

"orange".translate(table)
# 'puboif'
```

Comment: hi sir i cant understand the above procedure iam a beginner for python will you pls help me to solve this in simple without libraries??

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
import string

def dumb_encrypt(text, vowels='aeiou'):
    result = ''
    for char in text:
        i = string.ascii_letters.index(char)
        if char.lower() in vowels:
            result += string.ascii_letters[(i + 1) % len(string.ascii_letters)]
        else:
            c = 'a'
            for c in vowels:
                if string.ascii_letters.index(c) > i:
                    break
            result += c
    return result

print(dumb_encrypt('orange'))
# puboif
```

Basically, I would use `string.ascii_letters`, instead of defining that anew. Also, I would not convert all to list as it is not necessary for looping through. The consonants you got right. The vowels, I would just do an uncertain search for the next valid consonant. If the search, fails it sticks back to default `a` value.